# How can I change the Json casing format of the OAuth token returned by ASP WebAPI 2?

Tags: c#, json, oauth, asp.net-web-api2

I have a very basic and standard setup of ASP.NET WebApi 2 with OAuth bearer tokens implemented very similar to the following article: http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

The JSON response returned by the server containing the access token is formatted using snake_case. Is there a way that I can alter this to use camel / pascal casing?

My setup is very similar to that in the linked article, in which you can see in the images in step 12 and 13 that the JSON is formatted differently in the two requests despite configuring the JSON formatter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. These parameter names are part of the standard. Read RFC 6750: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750

Also note:

> Unless otherwise noted, all the protocol parameter names and values
> are case sensitive.